# Training loss becomes explodes and become NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning

I'm building an image regression model using the Inception V4 network. The entire network works when the number of training images used < 1000, both training and validation loss converges, but the training loss explodes to NaN when the number of images used for training is more than 1000. Any reason as to why this could happen?

Comment: Your model is suffering from exploding gradient.

Comment: Any reason as to why it doesn't happen when the training images < 1000?